# logging file not found when running from tests directory

Tags: python, pytest

My directory structure of project are as follows. When i run script from `package 1` it creates logs in `logs` directory but when i run from tests it can't file.

```
 /project
      __init__.py
     /flask_app
       __init__.py
       /scripts
         __init__.py
         logging.config.py
            /package1
              __init__.py
               mypython.py
            /logs
              logging.log
        /tests
          __init__.py
          test_mypython.py
```

`mypython.py` code:

```
 self.logger = configure_logger('log_handler','../logs/logging.py')
```

When i am running the mypython.py from tests by issuing command

```
   py.test
```

All i get response is

```
   [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
   /home/mac/project/flask_app/logs/logging.log
```

Which is clearly wrong as it tries to find path from tests directory

So far i have tried(mypython.py) using

```
log_file = pkg_resource.resource_filename(__name__, '../logs/logging.log')
self.logger = configure_logger('log_handler',log_file)
```

I also tried

```
package_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
log_file=os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../logs/logging.log')
```

None of them seem to work. If i change my directory to mypackage1 and then run `py.test` then everything works. I dont want that as i have other unit tests within tests directory. I am quite frustated now. Appreciate if anyone can point out what is wrong with my code. I thought package resource should resolve. clearly it hasn't . Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either configure logging with path related to the module (no to the current directory):

```
self.logger = configure_logger('log_handler', os.path.dirname(__file__) + '/../logs/logging.py')
```

or create `logs` directory before configuring logging with a relative path:

```
try:
    os.mkdir('../logs')
except OSError:  # Exists
    pass
self.logger = configure_logger('log_handler','../logs/logging.py')
```

Comment: Actually the problem was solved. using `os.path.dirname(__filename__),'.../log/logging.log)` . It was one of the files where it had not updated it. Thanks. I have incorporated your suggestion of creating logs file though which was missing.